# Plot vector field expressed in polar coordinates with quiver in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the following vector field expressed in polar coordinates:

```
E = r * R  % (i am using big R to represent r^ hat).
```

The field should look something like [figure P3.20](http://em.eecs.umich.edu/pdf/ulaby_solved_problems.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most difficult part is converting polar to euclidean coordinates:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-5:1:5,-5:1:5);

r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2); % r in function of (x, y)
theta = atan2(y, x); % theta in function of (x, y)

u = r.*cos(theta); % x component of the vector field
v = r.*sin(theta); % y component of the vector field

quiver(x, y, u, v)
```

[image]